# How do I get all set-cookies with axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to log in to a tcadmin through axios to get a cookie called "__TCAdmin2", but it's not returning this specific cookie. if you can help i thank you

[TCAdmin](https://painel.nicehosting.com.br/)
user: test
pass: test
Code:
`require('axios')('https://painel.nicehosting.com.br/Aspx/Interface/Base/Login.aspx', { 'headers': { 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', }, withCredentials: true, 'data':` __EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24Login1%24ButtonLogin&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24Login1%24TextBoxUserId=${user}&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24Login1%24TextBoxPassword=${pass}&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24Login1%24DropDownListLanguages=pt-BR&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24Login1%24DropDownListTheme=Default`,
'credentials': 'include',
'method': 'POST',

```
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers)
    const { responseUrl, rawHeaders } = response.request.res;

    console.log(rawHeaders)

}).catch(err => this.utils.logger(err));`
```

[result of above code](https://pastebin.com/mEXKBF2A)

I'm sorry for anything, it's the first time I create a topic here on stackoverflow

Comment: axios is for api requests. if you want to get a cookie use document.cookies or a cookie library.